# Assign strings to textfields in another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift3

I am trying to take facebook values, such as name and email, and transferring them to another view controller where they populate their corresponding text fields. However, when I try to populate the text fields with this code

```
 let fbEmail = data["email"]
 let fbName  = data["name"]

 func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       let vc = segue.destination as? CreateAccountVC
       vc!.emailTxt = self.fbName
       vc!.fullnameTxt = self.fbEmail
 }
```

I receive an error saying "Cannot assign type String to type UITextField!" I'm confused here as I thought that text fields only take strings (I'm very new to coding/programming).

So basically, how do I get these values gathered in one view controller to populate text fields in another view controller? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Error reason is you need to assign it to the `UITextField`'s text property. 
You can also use variables to set them. And set `textfield`'s values in your `CreateAccountVC` controller's  `viewDidLoad` function. Like this:

Your first controller where you take facebook values:

```
let fbEmail = data["email"]
let fbName  = data["name"]

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? CreateAccountVC {
           vc.emailTxtValue = self.fbName
           vc.fullnameTxtValue = self.fbEmail
    }
 }
```

Your CreateAccountVC :

```
class CreateAccountVC: UIViewController {
   var emailTxtValue:String?
   var fullnameTxtValue:String?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       emailTxt.text = emailTxtValue
       fullnameTxt.text = fullnameTxtValue
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't catch that. However, I just tried it and the text fields were not populated. Am I maybe using the wrong function to do this?

Comment: It was working in my tests. But I rearranged code lines and updated my answer. It is working for me and I hope it works for you :)

Comment: Still can not get it to work, maybe it has to do with the order/content of my code. Could I show you the entirety of my code?